# JQuery not reading user input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to get the date and department info stored into an array, when a user inputs a value into my HTML. When I look at the console, I see it is being saved as E.fn.init. Here is my HTML code:

```
<form>
<p><b>Date:</b><input id="date_out" type='date' required /></p> 
<p><b>Department:</b><input id='department_out' type='text' required /></p>

<button  class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id='submit' >SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

And here is my Javascript Code:

```
let count = 1;

// Handler to Submit Data
    $('#submit').click(() =>{
        $('form').on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

const date_out = $("#date_out").val();
const department_out = $("#department_out").val();

let data = [];

        // Iterate over all rows and store data
        for (let i = 1; i <= count; i++){

            // Skip Row if it was Removed
            if (!$(`tr[index=${i}]`).length) continue;

            // Store all Info from this row
            let assetInfo = {
            date_out: $(`#date_out${i}`).val(date_out),
            department_out: $(`#department_out${i}`).val(department_out),
        }
        
        data.push(assetInfo);
        console.log(data);
        }
    });
    });
```

And the console prints the array as; date_out: E.fn.init, department_out: E.fn.init. How do I get it to save whatever the user inputs in the array?

Comment: `$("#department_out").value` is not correct

Comment: Also here `date_out: $(`#date_out${i}`).val(date_out)` are you trying to set or get the value?

Comment: Please include all relevant code, Based on this `$(`#date_out${i}`)` it looks like you have more elements

Comment: When I did const date_out = document.getElementById('date_out').value; it still didn't work. But I am trying to get the value

Comment: You need `$("#department_out").val()`

Comment: I updated the code, but where would I put $("#department_out").val()? Where I declare it as a constant? Or within assetInfo?

Comment: We need to see more code, As i said this `$(`#date_out${i}`)` refers to that you have more elements. We need to see your html and also where does `count` in your for loop comes from

Comment: Is this enough code?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I was able to figure it out, but I apologize for not adding more code, I wasn't sure what more to add. But thank you very much for taking the time to respond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure what is your HTML structure but as I understand, you have a table and you want to store each row in a data,
here is how I advise you to do it:
In my Table called **depTable**, I have each row with a unique ID like this:

```
date_out_1
department_out_1
```

so, when I want to access that, I just want to create that **ID** which is an easy task while I can get how many rows I have in that table, like this:

```
// Get ROW COUNT FROM TABLE
var count = $('#depTable tr').length;
```

Now, if you combine in **For** loop you will get all **IDs**

```
for (let i = 1; i <= count; i++){
    var idDate = "#date_out_" + i;
    var idDep = "#department_out_" + i;
}
```

here is my all code, hope I helped to solve your problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Stack21</title>

    <script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<table id="depTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Department</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="date_out_1" type='date' required />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id='department_out_1' type='text' required />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="date_out_2" type='date' required />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id='department_out_2' type='text' required />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="date_out_3" type='date' required />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id='department_out_3' type='text' required />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="date_out_4" type='date' required />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id='department_out_4' type='text' required />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


<Button onclick="storeUserData()">Test me</Button>

<script>

    let data = [];

    function storeUserData(){
        // Get ROW COUNT FROM TABLE
        var count = $('#depTable tr').length;

        console.log("Row Count: " + count)

        for (let i = 1; i <= count; i++){
            var idDate = "#date_out_" + i;
            var idDep = "#department_out_" + i;

            let assetInfo = {
                date_out: $(idDate).val(),
                department_out: $(idDep).val()
            }

            data.push(assetInfo);
        }

        console.log(data);

    }


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Demo code here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Stack21</title>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- MY OFFLINE <script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script> -->
</head>
<body>

<table id="depTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Department</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="date_out_1" type='date' required />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id='department_out_1' type='text' required />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="date_out_2" type='date' required />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id='department_out_2' type='text' required />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="date_out_3" type='date' required />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id='department_out_3' type='text' required />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="date_out_4" type='date' required />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id='department_out_4' type='text' required />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


<Button onclick="storeUserData()">Test me</Button>

<script>

    let data = [];

    function storeUserData(){
        // Get ROW COUNT FROM TABLE
        var count = $('#depTable tr').length;

        console.log("Row Count: " + count)

        for (let i = 1; i <= count; i++){
            var idDate = "#date_out_" + i;
            var idDep = "#department_out_" + i;

            let assetInfo = {
                date_out: $(idDate).val(),
                department_out: $(idDep).val()
            }

            data.push(assetInfo);
        }

        console.log(data);

    }


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: My Result]

Comment: Thank you so much, I should have added more code, but this solved my problem! I just needed the var date_out = "#date_out". This whole time I thought I needed getElementById. But this gets the element, thank you

Comment: You are most welcome @HopeDunner :)